# Display all posts from single taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm not much of a PHP dev (front-end dev, mainly) and I'm struggling with getting a custom taxonomy term to display all posts using that term.

Here's the deal. I have:
1. A custom post type (attorneys)
2. A custom taxonomy for that post type (practice-areas)
3. A specific taxonomy term (appeals)

I need to display all "attorneys" posts that use the term "appeals" from the custom taxonomy "practice-areas". This will be displayed on the index page so I need to be specific with the query.

Here's my loop as it stands now:

`$loop = new WP_Query( 
        array(
            'post_type' => 'attorneys',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'taxonomy' => 'practice-areas',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => 'appeals',
                )
            )
        );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            // Get the content the_content;
            //Blah blah blah close loop
?>`

Comment: It should be noted this loop *kinda* works but isn't selecting the attorney post type by taxonomy term. It's simply printing *all* the attorneys without the taxonomy term filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the tax_query arrays

```
array(
        'post_type' => 'attorneys',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'practice-areas',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'appeals',
            )
        )
```

The `tax_query` parameter in `$loop` must look like this:

```
     $loop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'attorneys',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'practice-areas',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => 'appeals',
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

The `tax_query` parameter must be an array of array and the `field` parameter slug (as terms is not the term_id).

> Important Note: tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays (it takes an array of arrays). This construct allows you to query multiple taxonomies by using the relation parameter in the first (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the taxonomy arrays.

You can read more about the parameters available and their default values [Codex WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Hope it works!

Comment: Just a note, if you really want to display *all* "attorney posts, you might be tempted to set the posts_per_page parameter to -1, but don't. Pagination is always better.

Comment: Yes, @Charles, and I just edit my answer about the field parameter to change.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you! I read somewhere tax terms need to be an array within an array but forgot to implement that in my loop.